# How can I handle a mechanical justification for clerical magic in a world where gods are uncertain?

Tags: cleric, fudge

I'm making a Fudge campaign in a world where the existence of the gods is neither proven, nor disproven. I'd like to have multiple religions, many of which *may* be scams, but also *may be not*.

What mechanical justification (not narrative/lore) can I use for the existence of clerics, when a wizard could possibly have the same powers, with less restrictions?

(Note: Justification is a mechanical concept in Fudge. This question is not about world or culture.)

Comment: I want a *mechanical* justification, not a cultural one. How is that not an RPG question?

Comment: @JorgePujalteAbraham either way, a *"mechanic"* justification would depend on what game system is being used. Different systems might have different ways of justifying such a thing and trying to make this cover all system by asking a system agnostic question is just *way* too broad.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey It may be FUDGE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_(role-playing_game_system) that is being referenced. Jorge can you confirm?

Comment: That is the ruleset I'm intending to use. As it's so flexible, any compatible mechanic would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask how to make clear that there is a difference between wizards and clerics?

Comment: @Trish This is a game mechanics question, so Jorge is asking about an implementation detail.

Comment: @Jorge I've made some edits to try to clarify what this is about, and clarify that it isn't about worldbuilding or adding lore or world narrative based on my understanding from your comments. I've used some unusual wording, but to help prompt people to recognise this is a mechanical question and not asking for narrative worldbuilding details. Does this question still correspond to what you're looking for within Fudge? (If I've misunderstood somewhere along the line, please do correct me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Difference in source of magic.

While a difference in attitude to magic and the flavor around that could be enough I would argue that I would mechanically focus on the difference in the source of their magic/power.

A wizard would use the raw inner force of magic as learned from books and experimentation. While the cleric would draw power from his/her own belief in a concept (not a god per se) and the belief of others.

#### Pure Fudge

In pure Fudge you can apply this by setting the target difficulty level of the spell roll an extra step up or down based on the environment like the wizard going a step up if the area has had it's magic drained or down standing on a lay line. While a cleric spell roll difficulty level would go up if standing in location where satanic rituals are preformed and go down in an church.

#### Fate (light)

If you do not mind borrowing the Aspect mechanic from the Fate system you can use that to let players tap into their appropriate magic for their spells. This would mean that the wizard and cleric would be able to tag different aspects.

For instance a wizard would benefit from an "ley line" aspect he discovered earlier to be able to power up his/her spells while a Cleric could use an "solemn devotion" aspect of a church to power up his spell casting.

Comment: But, isn't aspects a Fate mechanic? (not that I'm not willing to incorporate it if needed)

Comment: you are correct. I thought it was core to fudge as it is used in other systems that ay they use the fudge system (and do not say Fate) I could rewrite this if you want

Comment: Please don't. This answer may inspire me to create some mechanics of my own.

Comment: I expanded the answer to answer both in pure Fudge and using the aspects system.

Comment: I'll accept this one as a good basis for my mechanics. Thanks!